# jQuery scrolling and changing the class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I am trying to add the following functionality to my site: when a user scrolls more than 400 pixels down the page, the first section of the page should be in opacity:0.4. This is the code I already unsuccesfully tried:

```
if($("html, body").offset().top >= 400){$("#main").addClass("scrolled");}

.scrolled {opacity:0.4;}
```

The jquery functions work, so there are no syntax errors I guess.

Thank you for any answer.

Comment: Debug your code in `Developer Tool` add `console.log("test1");` in if condition to check its coming in if condition or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to give a callback to `$.scroll` that will be called each time the scrolling position changes, then check if you are far enough.

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    // check the document scroll position
    if($(document).scrollTop() >= 400){
         $("#main").addClass("scrolled");
    } else {
         // if you also want to put #main back to normal
         $("#main").removeClass("scrolled");
    }
});
```

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8epkyL50/).

Comment: Thank you very much but it doesnt work. I put the video so you can check it. https://youtu.be/OdFhJ4sKa4w

Comment: @Hugo I think I'll need a bit more context then. The problem is likely to be elsewhere. I appended a jsfiddle at the end of my answer so you can see it working.

Comment: Ye, i am sorry, now it works, i dont understand, sorry for problems i have done to you, i am just 14 years old and i am not super programmer :) i just changed some thinks and suddenly it works. thank you :)

Comment: I'm glad you got it. Don't worry it is very common to get stuck because of seemingly tiny details. Keep coding!

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are looking for `.scrollTop()` not the `.offset().top` which results in a negative number as `html,body` is already have the `.offset().top` to `0` @ page load, and when you scroll at y axis results a negative number:

```
if($(document).scrollTop() >= 400){
     $("#main").addClass("scrolled");
}
```

use `$(document)` as the selector if you want to use `.scrollTop()` and i suppose you already have your `.scroll` event there.

---

### Note:

`$("html, body").offset().top` this selector you have results in negative `.offset().top` because `html,body` already have the `.offset().top` axis x/y to `0` when `DOMContentLoaded` event fired. so when you scroll vertically **you are actually scrolling to y axis which is a negative number**.